# How to change a webhook channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my discord bot to be able to imitate people, like Dad Bot does, but with custom text. My current code is:

```
 else if (command === 'sudo') {
    const sudoname = message.mentions.users.first().username
    if (sudoname === null) {
        return message.channel.send ('you need to mention someone.')
    }
    //remove the command
    const sudoreplace = message.content.replace('/sudo ', "")
    //remove the mention, we are left with the message
    const sudoreplace2 = sudoreplace.replace(args[0], "")
    const webhookpfp = message.mentions.users.first()
    //get mentioned user's avatar
    const webhookpfp2 = webhookpfp.avatarURL()
    const sudochannel = message.channel.id
    
    fetch(
        'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: sudoname,
            avatar_url:
              webhookpfp2,
            content:
              sudoreplace2,
          })
        }
    )
}
```

I know my way of replacing data is weird, but it works, it sends a message from the webhook with the profile and name of the mentioned user, but it only does that in one channel, set in the server webhook settings. Is there a way I can edit the webhook channel to the one that the command was executed in?

Here is an image of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjJrD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use discord.js's [`WebhookClient`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient) ( implements [`Webhook`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook))  Class like this:

```
const { Webhook } = require('discord.js');
const webhook = new Webhook('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

You can then use [`WebHook#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook?scrollTo=send) with [`WebhookMessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WebhookMessageOptions):

```
webhook.send(sudoreplace2, {avatarURL: webhookpfp2, username: sudoname});
```

Before you do that, you can change the channel with [`WebHook#edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook?scrollTo=edit):

```
webhook.edit({channel: message.channel});
```

Final summary:

```
const { Webhook } = require('discord.js');
const webhook = new Webhook('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
webhook.edit({channel: message.channel});
webhook.send(sudoreplace2, {avatarURL: webhookpfp2, username: sudoname});
```

Problems I faced with this: I ( Guild Owner ) created the Webhook, when the Bot tried to edit it, Discord API returned `DiscordAPIError: 401: Unauthorized`, I fixed this by using [`message.channel.createWebhook('PlaceHolder');`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createWebhook)

Comment: So ive done this, and your right, it does say unauthorized, but when i create the webhook with the bot, it only shows up in the channel it was created in, and the bot does not edit it with the same reason: unauthorized. I did change the const webhook variable to match the created one, but it still doesn't work. As long as i run the command in the channel it was created in, it works fine.

Comment: Give your Bot Administrator Permission, this might help. It works fine for me after letting the bot create it.